# is it possible to have flutter desktop app always on top on mac os?

Tags: flutter

I tried searching for any documentation / search results on this, but I couldn't find any, is it possible to have a macOS desktop app created with flutter always on top on macOS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default macOS Flutter application is just a standard `NSWindow` containing a Flutter view, so you would make it always on top the same way you would any other macOS application window, using [`NSWindowLevel`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindowlevel?language=objc).

There are two ways you can get to the window in your Flutter app:

- Drectly in MainFlutterWindow.swift, if your want it to always be on top.
- Via a plugin if you want to change it dynamically. `FlutterPluginRegistrar` has a `view` property that gives you the Flutter view, then you can get that view's `window`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this easily with the [window_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/window_manager) package.

```
import 'package:window_manager/window_manager.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await windowManager.ensureInitialized();

  windowManager.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```